# table returned from php not adding to given div using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

im trying to build a page that shows users the current forex rates live. So im grabbing the values from a feed and echo it into a table. Now i want to show to to the user using jquery.

The problem is i try to add the returned table to a div but the table doesn't add to the given div id. If firebug it shows the proper table in the console mode

my php

```
 echo '<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th class="instrument child_1">
                <span>Currency</span>
            </th>
            <th>
                <span>Buy</span>
            </th>
            <th">
                <span>Sell</span>
            </th>
            <th>
                <span>GMT Time</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';
       foreach ($xml->Rate as $rate) {
 echo' <tr>
       <td> '.$rate->Symbol.'</td>
            <td>
                 '.$rate->Buy.'
            </td>
            <td>
                '.$rate->Sell.'
            </td>
            <td>
               '.$rate->Last.'
            </td>';
 } 
 echo '        </tbody>
</table>';
```

Jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    new get_feed(); 

});

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function get_feed(){
    var feed = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "feed2.php",
        cache: false,
    }).success(function(){

        setTimeout(function(){get_feed();}, 10000);
    });
 $('#feeds').html(feed);

}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="feeds">

</div>
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Close </tr> in your echo

Comment: Whats with the use of the `new` keyword?

Comment: missed the <tr> thanks for pointing it out. i was going through some tutorials to run jquery every few seconds. Most of them has called the function using the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this ($.ajax call doesn't return value, you need to pass that trough success handler)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    get_feed(); 
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function get_feed(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "feed2.php",
        cache: false,
    }).success(function(data){
        $('#feeds').html(data);
        setTimeout(function(){get_feed();}, 10000);
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

your `</tr>` is not closed in `foreach loop`

```
foreach ($xml->Rate as $rate) {
 echo' <tr>
       <td> '.$rate->Symbol.'</td>
            <td>
                 '.$rate->Buy.'
            </td>
            <td>
                '.$rate->Sell.'
            </td>
            <td>
               '.$rate->Last.'
            </td>
      </tr>';        
 }
```

fill the value of div before time out code

```
success(function(){
        $('#feeds').html(feed);
        setTimeout(function(){get_feed();}, 10000);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    get_feed(); 
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function get_feed(){
    var feed = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "feed2.php",
        cache: false,
    }).success(function(data){
        $('#feeds').html(data);
        setTimeout(function(){get_feed();}, 10000);
    });
}
</script>
```

In your code var feed wont contain returned data , It will be contained in `data` inside success ,and thus giving call to same each function each 10 seconds , it will never go leaving function.Recursion cause repeat execution , so HTML should be written inside success  Here

Answer (score 0):

You have to **append html coming from ajax response in success callback** as shown below :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    get_feed(); 
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function get_feed(){
    var feed = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "feed2.php",
        cache: false,
        dataType:"html",   // <-----set datatype as html
    }).success(function(data){
        $('#feeds').empty().html(data);  //<-----add html to desired div here
        setTimeout(function(){ get_feed(); }, 10000);
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the new keyword, and since you are not posting any data, you can just use jquery's `load()` periodically:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var loadData = setInterval(function(){
        $('#feeds').load('feed2.php');
    }, 10000);

    //if you want to stop loading at some point
    $('#something').click(function(){
         clearInterval(loadData);
     });
});    
</script>
```